# Magento 2 - Credit Card Details Not Saved w/ Order

Tags: api, authorize.net, magento2.2

using latest Magento 2.3.0 here, in which I have a custom module that creates an order programmatically via API call.

Everything is working, and so far I've simply set the `payment method` (for testing / dev), I've not added any credit card details.

Now I'm simulating a credit card payment that goes through Authorize.net. Configured Mage 2 admin w/ the correct sandbox account settings, and added credit card details to the order in the custom module, but the transaction is not showing up in my Auth.net sandbox account - this is for `Authorization` only, not for capture/charge.

On closer inspection I assume that the cc details are not added to the order (only to the quote), hence the order when submitted does not authorize the transaction... (this is my assumption)

here's the code I use to add the cc details to the quote:

```
$quote->getPayment()->importData( 
    [
        'method' => "authorizenet_directpost",
        'cc_type' => $orderData['cc_data']['cc_type'],
        'cc_owner' => $orderData['cc_data']['cc_holder'],
        'cc_last_4' => substr($orderData['cc_data']['cc_num'], -4),
        'cc_number' => $orderData['cc_data']['cc_num'],
        'cc_cid' => $orderData['cc_data']['cc_ccv'],
        'cc_exp_month' => $orderData['cc_data']['cc_exp_month'],
        'cc_exp_year' => $orderData['cc_data']['cc_exp_year']
    ]
);
```

first questions:

(1) Are these the correct field names for the cc details ?
(2) Are all of these fields (e.g. cc_type) required ?

The quote is then converted to an order:

```
$quote->collectTotals()->save();
$order = $this->quoteManagement->submit($quote);
$this->orderSender->send($order);
```

Again, the order is created w/o any error, and in the admin order detail view I can see the Payment Information as `Credit Card Direct Post (Authorize.net)`, but no cc details at all.

The `quote_payment` db table has the cc data.

Final questions:

(3) Why are the cc details not properly added to the order and the authorization not being done ?
(4) Do I need to add the cc details to the order object instead to the quote object ?

Note: when I try to INVOICE these test orders, it fails w/ `Gateway error: Credit card number is required.`, so clearly the cc details are missing in the order...

Thanks !

Comment: can anybody help ?

Comment: Di you ever find an answer to this?